# How to utilize libserial with ROS -Ubuntu 12.04 - Hydro

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an old ROS Fuerte project which code i wanted to reuse in an another ROS Hydro node, this code uses libserial library.
I have a problem to find out the correct way to include this library into my new node via CMakeList.txt

Here what i include in my header:

```
#include <SerialStream.h>
using namespace LibSerial;
SerialStream fd;
```

I'm not totally sure where the error comes from but doesn't the "undefined reference" mean that problem could be within the compiling and linking?

Here is the error code:

```
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/x/Dropbox/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/x/Dropbox/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 20%] [ 20%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target serial_interface_generate_messages_cpp
[ 60%] [ 80%] Built target serial_interface_generate_messages_py
Built target serial_interface_generate_messages_lisp
[ 80%] Built target serial_interface_generate_messages
Linking CXX executable /home/x/Dropbox/catkin_ws/devel/lib/serial_interface/serial_interface
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
CMakeFiles/serial_interface.dir/src/serial_interface.cpp.o: In function `CA::RoverInterface::RoverInterface(ros::NodeHandle)':
serial_interface.cpp:(.text+0x514): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::Open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
CMakeFiles/serial_interface.dir/src/serial_interface.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x48): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::showmanyc()'
CMakeFiles/serial_interface.dir/src/serial_interface.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x50): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::xsgetn(char*, long)'
CMakeFiles/serial_interface.dir/src/serial_interface.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x58): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::underflow()'
CMakeFiles/serial_interface.dir/src/serial_interface.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x68): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::pbackfail(int)'
CMakeFiles/serial_interface.dir/src/serial_interface.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x70): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::xsputn(char const*, long)'
CMakeFiles/serial_interface.dir/src/serial_interface.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[vtable for LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf]+0x78): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::overflow(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/x/Dropbox/catkin_ws/devel/lib/serial_interface/serial_interface] Error 1
make[1]: *** [serial_interface/CMakeFiles/serial_interface.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have updated my `CMakeList.txt` file to be as follows with the new information I got from an answer:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(serial_interface)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
   
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

 add_message_files(
   FILES
   Control.msg
 )

generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime
)

add_executable(serial_interface src/serial_interface.cpp)
add_dependencies(serial_interface serial_interface_generate_messages_cpp)

target_link_libraries(serial_interface
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   libserial0
 )

 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
 )
```

And if i run `dpkg -L libserial0`

I do get the following:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libserial0
/usr/share/doc/libserial0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libserial0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libserial.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libserial.so.0
```

Therefore I should have the correct library installed on my system? Anyway i still receive this error while trying to run `catkin_make`.

```
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/x/Dropbox/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/x/Dropbox/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [ 20%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target serial_interface_generate_messages_cpp
[ 40%] [ 80%] Built target serial_interface_generate_messages_lisp
Built target serial_interface_generate_messages_py
Linking CXX executable /home/x/Dropbox/catkin_ws/devel/lib/serial_interface/serial_interface
[ 80%] Built target serial_interface_generate_messages
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibserial0
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/x/Dropbox/catkin_ws/devel/lib/serial_interface/serial_interface] Error 1
make[1]: *** [serial_interface/CMakeFiles/serial_interface.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127866/how-to-utilize-libserial-with-ros--ubuntu-12.04---hydro/) by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Undefined reference" usually means that you're compiling against the headers for a library, but aren't linking to that library during your final link phase.

In CMake, you usually link an executable to a library using the `target_link_libraries()` command.

Depending on if or how you're finding the libserial package from CMake, you'll want to do different things.

If you're using find_package to find libserial, you'll want something like:

```
target_link_libraries(my_node ${libserial_LIBRARIES})
```

But if you're just assuming that the system has libserial installed, and you normally pass `-lserial` to link to it, you probably want to do:

```
target_link_libraries(my_node serial)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on 2014-02-11**:
I updated my question and it seems I do not have the correct library name which to use for linking?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-02-11**:
Leave off the `lib` prefix. You probably want `-lserial`, so put `serial` in your target_link_libraries(), as @ahendrix suggested.

**Comment by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on 2014-02-11**:
ok this works, although there is another error now but its not related to this question anymore.

**Comment by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on 2014-02-11**:
the new problem is this error, not sure if its still related to linking:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to` main'

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-11**:
That sounds like a new question.

**Comment by [ajr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/1453/ajr_/) on 2014-02-11**:
Ok, actually missing the main function & node. Beginners mistake... This problem is solved, thanks to all for the help!